# angular 4 how to access ViewChildren _results

Tags: javascript, angular

i have a list of checkboxes inside an ngFor:

```
    <md-checkbox
      #hangcheck
      [id]="hangout?.$key"
      class="mychecks"
      >
    I'm Interested
  </md-checkbox>
```

i refrence them in the component like so:

```
@ViewChildren("hangcheck") hangchecks: QueryList<any>;
```

then in ngAfterViewInit i need to loop them:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(){
console.log('the array: ',this.hangchecks)
this.hangchecks._results.forEach((item) => {
  console.log('the item: ',item)
});
 }
```

but i get:
Property '_results' is private and only accessible within class 'QueryList'
 in the console i see this:
[image]
so as you can see there is the array in the _results. but how can i access it and loop it?

Answer (score 25):

Call the `toArray()` method:

```
this.hangchecks.toArray().forEach((item) => {
```

Comment: the log inside the loop is not being executed =      this.hangchecks.toArray().forEach((item) => {
      console.log('the item: ',item.id)
    });

Comment: what does `console.log(this.hangchecks.toArray())` print?

Comment: empty array- []length: 0__proto__: Array(0) but as you seen in the picture the array has 2 elements

Comment: But I don't know how you came to this picture if the array is empty. Try to subscribe to `changes`.  `this.hangchecks.changes.subscribe(c => { this.hangchecks.toArray().forEach((item) => { console.log(item);});`. I guess your elements are created by `*ngIf` or `*ngFor` from async data and not yet available when above `console.log()` is executed.

Comment: @Ron Check also this https://plnkr.co/edit/ZCQlgH83N4kWW9eewHx8?p=preview

Comment: ok the subscribe does allow me to access them, at least it log them

Comment: maybe its not the angular way, but it answers the question asked and works great.

Comment: This works, but my IDE still shows that _results is private(...)

Comment: @AleksGrunwald that's because it IS private. If you want to access all elements as an array, skip the `.forEach(...)` part like `let items = this.hangchecks.toArray();`

Answer (score 4):

To access elements, you have to wait until its ready

```
this.hangchecks.changes.subscribe(a => a.forEach((b, i) => console.log(b)));
```

Answer (score 0):

To access ith element in _results in the queryList, call `toArray()` method:

`this.queryListObj.toArray().[i]`

Comment: How is this different, and better, than the existing similar 5 years old answer?